# React testing 3rd party component inside my functional component

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

How I can test 3rd party component inside my component? All the handlers are inside my functional component.

I'm using jest and enzyme.

Example:

```
export const Index = () => {
   <CompA onClick /> // this is tested
   <3rdPartyComp onClose onFinish initialValues ... /> // how to test this?
}
```

On click opens in modal the 3rd party component and viceversa 3rd party component onClose needs to close it.

How to mock the 3rd party component? Or some other way where I setProps and simulate click on those props I set.

Minimal code I've tried so far:

If the 3rd party component is like this below:

```
<Comp onClose onFinish ... />
```

Then in jest runner I'm doing this:

```
const onClose = expect(wrapper.find(SomeComp).prop('onClose'));
if (onClose) {
   onClose(() => false);
}
expect(...);
```

and this works, even I'm not sure if is the best way to do it

Br,

Comment: Why are you testing a 3rd party component? That's the job of the library itself. You usually just test your own code

Comment: It's wizard which happens most of the bootstrap code of the app, and I need to use those 'reusable' components. So I like to simulate closing of the wizard, nothing more. Other components there are loaded on every step in the wizard I will test in isolation.

Comment: How have you tried interacting with the third party component in the test? How are you providing mock handlers in the test? How are you testing that the handlers have been called?

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky that's the question, i like to provide mock component with mock props.

Comment: Don't test 3rd party code, you should expect for it to already be adequately unit tested when consuming it. Unit test ***your*** code. Or is your question more about mocking it so you can test `Index` component? What have you tried?

Comment: @DrewReese updated my initial question with small snippet what i've achieved so far. I understand that I don't need to test 3rd party code. But is wizard which loads components and u progress through the wizard, so I like to write tests for all changes inside the wizard till the onFinish handler.

Comment: You *may* find using [react-testing-library](https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/intro/) a little better suited for testing your UI. It's a bit different than enzyme, but IMO better since it focuses on exercising the component in much the same manner a user would.

Comment: I'd recommend to add the actual tests you have written so far. This may not really about "testing" the third party component, but if it does have effects on state, props, or handlers  of `CompA` or the parent, it would still be worth testing. You probably wouldn't even need to mock it, you just need to create stubs for the handlers. It's difficult to really troubleshoot without seeing the code and/or test cases/assertions. You wrote a portion of it, but not the actual expectations/assertions you are trying.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to test the 3rd party components and codes. The responsibility for testing belongs to the 3rd party library. If the 3rd party library does not have any test, it is not recommended to use it. You should use the 3rd party library with well-tested.

For your example, you should test the code logic and behavior of your component.

Please provide [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), so we can know how to test it.

Comment: One way I've used is like this: 
const onClose = expect(wrapper.find(SomeComp).prop('onClose'));
onClose(() => false);
This way I'm extracting the prop and call the fn
I'm not sure if is the best solution....
Also the problem is that the handler in my component are actually useCallback's... which interally calls setState and flip-flop true/false flag